# PyGame slower on macOS than on Ubuntu or Raspbian

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

I use PyGame for creating games, but I noticed that the programs ran a lot slower on macOS than on my Raspberry Pi. My original solution was to install Ubuntu alongside macOS on my computer, and that worked. However, I would rather only have one operating system on my computer. Does anyone know why PyGame is so much slower on my mac when running macOS?

If it would help, I can send code. However, I have multiple PyGame programs and they all do the exact same thing, so I figured that it was most likely not the fault of the code, but I could be wrong.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

P.S. When I say slower, I mean that it is running at about 30% of the speed on macOS than it would on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is you pygame and/or SDL version the same on both platforms?  How disparate is the hardware?

Comment: I'm ran ubuntu and macos on the same computer, ubuntu worked faster for pygame. Pygame was also faster on my ***raspberry pi*** than my MacBook. So the hardware on my mac is better yet pygame is slower. A lot slower. @Kingsley

Comment: This question is on Python 2.7, but should still work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685936/pygame-application-runs-slower-on-mac-than-on-pc

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I tried both of those answers. I have pygame running on low resolution. Also, I completely removed the `clock.tick()` link from the program. Still had the same problem.

Comment: I don't know about the PyGame module, but Python works fine on my Mac. It might be a problem with the PyGame module.

Comment: How many FPS you're getting on each platform? This might be an issue where you're not calculating movement with the elapsed time in place, just relying on the actual frames. If your game feels "slow" that might be the issue.

Comment: Can you do some benchmarking and post the results here? That should give us an idea about where the bottleneck is

Comment: is display set to window or full screen?  I couldn't get window to work on my Mac, it was slow and laggy.  Setting to fullscreen solved the problem.  I then tried pygame 2.0.0.dev6 and everything was working as it should on both Mac and windows.

Comment: @James I will try setting it to full screen, but that still doesn't solve the initial problem -- but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @WoLfulus My fps is fine... The game is very smooth, however, the boxes move slower on my mac than on my raspberry pi. I have the same problem across multiple games in the same way. I even tried removing all sleep and clock.tick() statements, but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pygame is based on the [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) library. It supports using [various rendering backends](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER), such as `OpenGL` and `metal`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59725539/2907819) (and the comment), it seems that the `metal` renderer might perform poorly on mac. Sadly, according to [this issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1725), it seems that in most versions of pygame, it uses `metal` as the SDL backend for mac, and provides no way to change that.

There is the `pygame.OPENGL` flag you could pass to `pygame.display.set_mode()`, but I'm not sure exactly how it would affect anything. It might be a good idea to play with the other flags listed [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

I'd recommend you to [open an issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/new) on pygame's official github repo with the necessary details. Also, as a workaround, you could clone pygame, change the default renderer on mac to OpenGL, compile, and see if it improves anything. You can use the issue I mentioned above to understand where you should start.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. It makes sense that it would be slower because of different renderers, especially since macOS isn't really geared towards games... What I can probably do is thread my game, so that it updates the screen less often than it updates player position, so the boxes will more at the same speed just at a lower fps.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your game in full screen mode

```py
pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Oddly enough this mostly worked for me, it went from an abyssmal 11 FPS or worse to 50 FPS

Comment: This works for me, but can you please explain why? And is there a way to get the speed of this to work in non-full screen mode?

Comment: Well from what i could find it seems like it’s an issue with how the game renders like the top comment mentioned mostly because of the mac’s screen resolution. However when the game is set to full screen i think it drops the resolution because nothing has to run other than the game so it performs better. Hope this explains it :)

Comment: I think so. I tried to set the game to run in low resolution mode but they seemed to have removed that setting in OSX Catalina :(

Comment: I just checked and it's still there. I am also running OSX Catalina. To find it you should right click the application you're trying to start then select 'Get Info'. Once the popup opens you should find an option for 'Lower Resolution Mode'.

Comment: That options doesn't show up for me. Unsure what OS settings i need to change to make it visible, but it's missing from the 'get info' screen when I click on the python executable running the game.

Answer (score -1):

MacOS is generally slower

Unless you can install a second RAM stick it will always be that way